# Display Rich Text field value with proper alignment in page block table column

Tags: visualforce, html

I need to display a column value with the proper format.
Let me explain my situation,

Am entering hint values in a Rich Text field and trying to display it in a pageblock table column.Am using show toggle function to that particular column based on the user click event on the other column.

Am entring the values as line by line.

> Line 1
>   Line 2
>   Line 3

When am seeing the rich text field value with the created record it is displaying properly with line by line.

But if I assign this field value to page block table column it is coming as a paragraph instead of line by line.

> Line1 Line2 Line3

Also am using a div tag inside of apex column to show/hide the rich text field value based on the user clicks.If user clicks first column the second column will be shown/hidden.

So what I need do to display this rich text field value line by line...Is there any way to make it work...

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks -
Chitra

Comment: Have you considered using standard html tables or lists instead of apex? Otherwise, I suspect you're going to want to use JS or jQuery.

Comment: Could you please elaborate..

Comment: At a minimum, your Hints need to be in a list `li` or pageblock. You could also put them in a Table. You need show/hide functionality. It sounds like you prob need Hover/MouseOver/OnClick/MouseOut functionality to provide that. jQuery would simplify much of that for you. A Table with CSS will align much better than a pageblock.

Comment: did you get any solution for this problem? If you have any solution please share.